# Ошибка с подключением прокси в питон

Tags: python, proxy, веб-скрейпинг

Парсил сайт и владелец заблокировал мой айпи. Пытался и через впн и вкобчать прокси в код но выдает такая ошибка:
"Exception has occurred: ProxyError
HTTPSConnectionPool(host='svgmix.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /ru/collections/phosphor-duotone (Caused by ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x0000024BDD6A52D0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it')))
ConnectionRefusedError: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

urllib3.exceptions.NewConnectionError: <urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x0000024BDD6A52D0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='svgmix.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /ru/collections/phosphor-duotone (Caused by ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x0000024BDD6A52D0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it')))"

Вот кусок кода

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd


cookies = {
    'XSRF-TOKEN': 'eyJpdiI6Imo3RktZV3YvOFVORkUwU3pRc0RvZ3c9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiQ0xJbUhRV2hFUEFyOVhRaC9qR2ZseXdZZWZWbllGSm9sSjdCUUNYWXRxVTRFQkxnQndmcGJWeDdJOEhXQ09lWmJLcWJSZ1pRb2wxSXg3L3JIZ2JvdzVoeEYzaFNUZjFpR1B0cTdCYTZERjlBeDU0SEFsQUJsa00xWDBsMWZ5U2UiLCJtYWMiOiI4ODM2MzNmMjRjNDBhODIwMGY3YTdiNDQzNzUzYWU0OGZkZjBjNmMxNDJmNGE5NTM5OGE5ZmVmYTMzZjBlMDU3IiwidGFnIjoiIn0%3D',
    'svgmix_session': 'eyJpdiI6Imh0d1ZlYmNWNEw4RGtxZTJua01FQVE9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiYStZRFFqWlB6c3hwUDJGVDFySytLV1JrS0FnV2J6eVQ4MHNoMEk0OXUyclJxeVZ3b2ZWT3Y2MnBXV2lham5BTnZVZS9Za1dzYnRnQy9FK0dYaVhEejFUV2daeVFtazh1YzlLWTY3NHA2RGJ0N24rQlpBcU5UbVVPUjJxZzhpQjgiLCJtYWMiOiIyNDZjZTYyMWFhYjU5ZTMzODYzNWE1NGMxOTllYzdmNzFiYWExMmZhZmE2ZTc1YjMyMzdhMmM4Zjc4ZjU1ZDgwIiwidGFnIjoiIn0%3D',
    'cf_clearance': '73bO0XB2.pkQjv09okeaQU3Q5_Qo_KhdDOhFEsrt6ug-1690305709-0-0.2.1690305709',
}

headers = {
    'authority': 'svgmix.com',
    'accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.7',
    'accept-language': 'ru-RU,ru;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7,uk;q=0.6',
    'cache-control': 'no-cache',
    # 'cookie': 'XSRF-TOKEN=eyJpdiI6Imo3RktZV3YvOFVORkUwU3pRc0RvZ3c9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiQ0xJbUhRV2hFUEFyOVhRaC9qR2ZseXdZZWZWbllGSm9sSjdCUUNYWXRxVTRFQkxnQndmcGJWeDdJOEhXQ09lWmJLcWJSZ1pRb2wxSXg3L3JIZ2JvdzVoeEYzaFNUZjFpR1B0cTdCYTZERjlBeDU0SEFsQUJsa00xWDBsMWZ5U2UiLCJtYWMiOiI4ODM2MzNmMjRjNDBhODIwMGY3YTdiNDQzNzUzYWU0OGZkZjBjNmMxNDJmNGE5NTM5OGE5ZmVmYTMzZjBlMDU3IiwidGFnIjoiIn0%3D; svgmix_session=eyJpdiI6Imh0d1ZlYmNWNEw4RGtxZTJua01FQVE9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiYStZRFFqWlB6c3hwUDJGVDFySytLV1JrS0FnV2J6eVQ4MHNoMEk0OXUyclJxeVZ3b2ZWT3Y2MnBXV2lham5BTnZVZS9Za1dzYnRnQy9FK0dYaVhEejFUV2daeVFtazh1YzlLWTY3NHA2RGJ0N24rQlpBcU5UbVVPUjJxZzhpQjgiLCJtYWMiOiIyNDZjZTYyMWFhYjU5ZTMzODYzNWE1NGMxOTllYzdmNzFiYWExMmZhZmE2ZTc1YjMyMzdhMmM4Zjc4ZjU1ZDgwIiwidGFnIjoiIn0%3D; cf_clearance=73bO0XB2.pkQjv09okeaQU3Q5_Qo_KhdDOhFEsrt6ug-1690305709-0-0.2.1690305709',
    'pragma': 'no-cache',
    'referer': 'https://svgmix.com/ru',
    'sec-ch-ua': '"Not.A/Brand";v="8", "Chromium";v="114", "Google Chrome";v="114"',
    'sec-ch-ua-mobile': '?0',
    'sec-ch-ua-platform': '"Windows"',
    'sec-fetch-dest': 'document',
    'sec-fetch-mode': 'navigate',
    'sec-fetch-site': 'same-origin',
    'sec-fetch-user': '?1',
    'upgrade-insecure-requests': '1',
    'user-agent':  'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:52.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/69.0'
}
proxies = {
   'http': '51.195.11.118',
  'https': '51.195.11.118',

}


def get_data(links):
    for url in links:
        r = requests.get(url, headers=headers, cookies=cookies, proxies=proxies)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')
        icons = soup.find_all('div', class_='col-6 col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 col-xl-1')
```

Answer (score 0):

Строка прокси должна выглядеть так: `http://username:password@ip:port` `username:password@` - не обязательно Вот пример использования прокси (Прокси взят с https://free-proxy-list.net/):

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


headers = {
    'authority': 'svgmix.com',
    'accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.7',
    'accept-language': 'ru-RU,ru;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7,uk;q=0.6',
    'cache-control': 'no-cache',
    'pragma': 'no-cache',
    'referer': 'https://svgmix.com/ru',
    'sec-ch-ua': '"Not.A/Brand";v="8", "Chromium";v="114", "Google Chrome";v="114"',
    'sec-ch-ua-mobile': '?0',
    'sec-ch-ua-platform': '"Windows"',
    'sec-fetch-dest': 'document',
    'sec-fetch-mode': 'navigate',
    'sec-fetch-site': 'same-origin',
    'sec-fetch-user': '?1',
    'upgrade-insecure-requests': '1',
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:52.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/69.0'
}
proxies = {
    'http': 'http://139.162.102.27:32539',
    'https': 'https://139.162.102.27:32539',

}

r = requests.get("https://whoer.net/ru", headers=headers, proxies=proxies)
soap = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "lxml")
print(soap.find("strong", {"class": "your-ip"}).text)
```

Comment: Исправил, все равно выдает ту же ошибку

Comment: @haess ошибку выдаёт именно кусок кода в ответе или исправленный ваш?

Comment: исправленный мой

Comment: @haess Если вы использовали свой прокси то проверьте код используя прокси из ответа, либо вы можете проверить свой прокси используя код из ответа. (Прокси из ответа может работать через раз)

Comment: Если через мой прокси то все равно выдает ту же ошибку ProxyEror, а если через прокси с ответа то такую ошибку:
"Exception has occurred: SSLError
HTTPSConnectionPool(host='svgmix.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /collections/phosphor-duotone (Caused by SSLError(SSLEOFError(8, 'EOF occurred in violation of protocol (_ssl.c:992)')))
ssl.SSLEOFError: EOF occurred in violation of protocol (_ssl.c:992)"

Comment: @haess Проверьте используя ответ из [этого](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33410577/python-requests-exceptions-sslerror-eof-occurred-in-violation-of-protocol?answertab=trending#tab-top) вопроса

Comment: теперь выдает о подключении, пробовал увеличивать таймаут
"Exception has occurred: ConnectTimeout
HTTPSConnectionPool(host='svgmix.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /collections/phosphor-duotone (Caused by ConnectTimeoutError(<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x0000021FBA1DA3D0>, 'Connection to 12.218.209.130 timed out. (connect timeout=100)'))
TimeoutError: [WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond"